# SQL - Select query not displaying all dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a start date, an end date, and the pay period information according to the start and end dates. When I try to find the pay period information with a date range, the very first pay period information does not show in the result.

For example, when I run the following query:

```
select *
FROM PayPeriod
where start_date between '2020-12-01' and '2020-12-21'
```

I should see the following result:

```
Start_date  End_date    Pay_perild
2020-11-22  2020-12-05  2020-12-wk1
2020-12-06  2020-12-19  2020-12-wk3
2020-12-20  2021-01-02  2021-01-wk1
```

Instead, I get:

```
Start_date  End_date    Pay_period
2020-12-06  2020-12-19  2020-12-wk3
2020-12-20  2021-01-02  2021-01-wk1
```

The date range and the pay period that includes '2020-12-01' is omitted. Why isn't it showing, and how do I correct this?

Comment: But 2020-11-22 is not between '2020-12-01' and '2020-12-21' ?

Comment: @AlexK - I see what you mean. I'm trying to figure this out...

Comment: So you want all Pay Periods that occur (in whole or in part) within your period of interest. Often, when you think about writing your requirements in text, it becomes easier to see what the logic you need, Start date of pay period is before your end date parameter and end date of pay period is after your start date parameter. A simple time line graph will help you visualize the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I've got what you wanted. You need to intersect two time intervals.

To find intersecting intervals of two tables (say `TableA` and `TableB`, I use tables as more general case to distinguish two intervals by their meaning/role/whatever) you need to compare begin date of one table with end date of another for both tables (putting each of them to "one" and "another" role):

```
TableA.start_date < TableB.end_date
and TableB.start_date < TableA.end_date
```

It is the rule for the case where your intervals are continuous, e.g. `end_date` of one period is "just before" (like real numbers) of the `start_dare` of another (so all items in the interval will have `start_date <= item_date < end_date`). For discrete intervals (like days, where duration of one day will have identical values of `start_date` and `end_date`) there would be `<=` in intersection condition.

So, your query will look like

```
DECLARE @period_from date = CONVERT ('2020-12-01' 23),
  @period_to date = CONVERT ('2020-12-21', 23);

select *
FROM PayPeriod
where start_date < @period_to /*or <= depending on inclusion of end_date*/
  and @period_from < end_date /*or <= depending on inclusion of end_date*/
```

Answer (score 2):

The query is returning the result as you instructed. It's working perfectly. In your query you put the date range condition one the start_date:

```
where start_date between '2020-12-01' and '2020-12-21'
```

The first row that you expect has start_date = 2020-11-22. This date is not in the rage you specified in the condition.

If you want the first row in the result set simply you need to change the condition.
If you have to put condition on the start date you have to make the date range wider in the condition. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM PayPeriod
WHERE start_date between '2020-11-21' and '2020-12-21'
```

Based on your application requirement you have to arrange the condition.

Comment: Makes sense. So what I need to figure out is to find a way to get the results with a date range that falls either between or on the start date and the end date.

Comment: Yes, based on your application it might be start date or end date or both.